# How to improve performance of CALayer animations?

Tags: ios, uiview, core-animation, calayer

while studying Core Animation, I've made a UIView category which makes a subview be broken into a lot of tiles and diffused.
https://github.com/minorblend/HNTileDisappear
However, when the number of tiles are not small FPS of animation drops steeply.
Is there any way or idea to improve the performance of this kind of CALayer animation?

Answer (score 2):

A few things come to mind:

1) set `shouldRasterize` to YES on your layers

2) don't use fractional values in frames if you can

3) make your layers opaque

4) try also setting the `drawsAsynchronously` property on the layers

Comment: Is rasterizing still helpful even if layer is animated along paths? btw, I want to support iOS >= 5 so can't use drawSynchronously property and already use rintf() to make all values integer in layers' frames

Comment: Not sure if it helps specifically with path animations. I've used it in regular animations with good results. You can test if it helps using Instruments.

Comment: shouldn't the property name be drawsAsynchronously?

Comment: @Monobono yes, thank you :) I was probably typing too fast. Will correct the answer now.